# Replacing multiple consecutive spaces by a single space in a string

Tags: c#, string, spaces

I currently have this class to replace consecutive spaces by one:

```
public static string RemoveSpacesLoop(string value)
{
   if(value.Contains("  "))
   {
       return RemoveSpacesLoop(value.Replace("  ", " "));
   }
   else
   {
       return value;
   }
}
```

It works, but in the long run it may cause performance issues. is there a way to simplify this ?

Comment: What's the point for the recursive call? According to docs, Replace returns "A string that is equivalent to the current string except that all instances of oldValue are replaced with newValue."

Comment: Have you compared the performance to doing it as a `while` loop?

Comment: @Andrei In case there were four spaces in a row?

Comment: why don't use value.Replace("  ","") ?

Comment: I suppose you want to collapse multiple spaces into one, not generally "remove spaces"??

Comment: @tom He wants to replace multiple spaces with a single space, not remove them entirely.

Comment: A good specification is the first step towards a good program.

Comment: @DGibbs..yeah sorry I missed that !

Comment: It can be done with a single pass copying array of characters. Copy by character, remember when space was copied to skip copying further consecutive spaces. Make 2 passes to know destination array size or use list.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Regex`. For example:

```
var x = "123  456 789    999   0";
var y = Regex.Replace(x, @"\s{2,}", " ");
```

It will replace all multiple spaces with single one.

You can also iterate over characters in string and produce new string comparing that characters with spaces something like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
bool isSpaceFound = false;

foreach (char c in x)
{
    if (c == ' ')
    {
        if (!isSpaceFound)
            sb.Append(c);

        isSpaceFound = true;
    }
    else
    {
        isSpaceFound = false;
        sb.Append(c);
    }
}

var y = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Explanation: \s is regex syntax for space {2,} means 2 consecutive or more. So this regular expression looks for 2 or more consecutive spaces and replaces them with a single space.

Comment: problem with this is that it is slow @andykomeyev

Comment: @user3702989 how long are strings you are working with? For Regex to be slow it should be very long strings - probably megabytes of length.

Comment: @user3702989 You can't just say "...it is slow" without any qualification. Compared to snails it is lightening quick. Define slow.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev they can be anything from 25 to 1

Comment: @user3702989 "*from 25 to 1*"? What does it means? What is your measurement units? Is it string length or spaces count?

Comment: @AndyKorneyev that is string length

Comment: @user3702989 and what is measurement units of that "25"? bytes, kilobytes, megabytes?

Comment: @user3702989 Anyway, if you don't want to use regexes - you can iterate characters from string one-by-one and do some simple comparison. I've updated the answer with the sample. And yes, I really doubt that method to join multiple spaces faster than this exists . ;)

Comment: @AndyKorneyev its a string of 25 characters

Comment: @user3702989 Oh, trust me - regex can't be really slow on a string of 25 characters. It can be slightly slower than iterating character one-by-one, but difference is insignificant